# How to handle multiple daily deployments resetting Prometheus metrics

Tags: django, monitoring, prometheus, metrics

My team just started using Prometheus for monitoring our Django web application ([django-prometheus](https://github.com/korfuri/django-prometheus)). Like any common setup, metrics are published to a "/metrics" endpoint, which is scraped by Prometheus.

Our problem is the fact that we deploy several times a day. On every deployment, the metrics are reset (all counters, gauges, etc. go back to zero) so we never have more than a few hours of metrics to review.

I'd imagine this is a common problem with Prometheus. Is more than a few hours worth of aggregated metrics okay? Is there something I should do to persist metrics at any point in the pipeline?

Comment: Counter resets are absolutely normal - https://www.robustperception.io/how-does-a-prometheus-counter-work - but what do you mean by "gauges reset back to zero"? Gauges are for things that have a current value.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski How do you retain data from deployment to deployment then?